# when I downloading file from google drive with java i get symbols

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-drive-api

when I downloading file from google drive with java I get response like that in pic
[image]

there is my code

```
public void downloadFile(String fileId, OutputStream outputStream) {
        if (fileId != null) {
            try {
                googleDriveService.getInstance().files()
                    .get(fileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
            } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

there is also my controller

```
@GetMapping("/download/{fileId}")
    public void download(@PathVariable String fileId, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            documentService.downloadFile(fileId, response.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What data do you expect to be in the file?

Comment: it can be any type of mime type

Comment: What makes you think that there's a problem with the data in your image?

Comment: I upload any type of file for ex(pdf, jpg, docx) when I download I get any way symbols like that

Comment: You're trying to view binary content as text.

Comment: And does the file still work as a PDF or jpg after you download it? Those symbols are just how bytes not in the standard ASCII set appear when your terminal displays them. What makes you think something is wrong?

Comment: My guess is that it's simply a matter of what app you're using to view the file.  What app is giving you that view of the file?  It looks like you're trying to view a binary file as text. 
 What platform are you on?  What's the file extension/type?  Try to load the file with the correct app for the file type and see if you get the behavior you expect.

Comment: I get it in browser

Comment: What kind of file is it?

Comment: it can be any type of file(pdf, jpg, docx)

Comment: The file in test has binary content. When you are trying to print them on console, those binaries are taken as non-printable characters and replaced with 'Replacement Character'.

Comment: Unless the file is corrupted, the problem is that the file is not being interpreted correctly given its type.  I don't know what OS you're on, what the file type/extension is, or how you're opening the file, but there's some mismatch in all of that such that the wrong thing is happening when your system tries to open the file.

Comment: If you're on Windows, is the file extension correct for the type of the file?  If the extension is right, and the file is a pdf, jpeg, or docx, then it shouldn't be opened in your browser when you double-click on the file.  Rather, it should be opened by the appropriate app for that file type.  It's hard to know just what's going wrong since you've left out so many details about what you're doing.

Comment: @Steve I use Linux mint, i want download in browser file type is docx(but this not matter because when i want to download pdf i get symbols such that)

Comment: @Steve I also add my controller

Comment: The first two bytes of the file are P K == 50 4B which is consistent with a ZIP file or a file format that is based on ZIP.  Microsoft docx format is based on ZIP.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)  My diagnosis is that the file is probably OK ... and the problem is either with the tool you are using to open it, or the way you are using the tool.

Comment: Thanks for that.  That was the key to allowing me to understand what's going on.  See my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that you aren't setting the ContentType header in your HTTP response, and so your browser doesn't know what to do with the data coming back in the response body.  To get the right behavior from your browser, you should set the ContentType header appropriately for the type of data you are returning.

For a JPEG, you want to call something like:

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
```

For a PDF, you want to call:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

For "docx", it's strange, but it seems that what you want is:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
```

Doing this should cause your browser to properly display any file type that it knows how to display.

Lacking any type information, I believe that the browser is interpreting the data as plain text, which is why you're seeing the funny display that you are.

UPDATE: Per the original poster's comment, the Google Drive API allows to get the MIME type of a downloaded file via the call:

```
String mimeType = googleDriveService.getInstance().files().get(fileId).execute().getMimeType();
```

This value can then be used to set the ContentType header in the response, via:

```
response.setContentType(mimeType);
```

The addition of these two lines of code should cause the OP's code to return the correct mime type for any type of file uploaded to Google Drive, thereby causing the requesting browser to properly display any file type it knows what to do with.

Comment: Thanks a lot I  get mimeType like that and set it to content type String mimeType = googleDriveService.getInstance().files().get(fileId).execute().getMimeType();

Comment: Ah...excellent!  I haven't ever used the Google Drive API.  It makes sense that they'd have such a call to make this an easier thing to deal with.  I'm glad you were able to find that API call to make your code work right.

Comment: Do you know why I get zip of xml files for doc and docx and xlsx files?

Comment: No, I don't know about that.  What does your browser do with those files when you return the right MIME type?

Comment: download the zip file with collection of xml files

Comment: Ah...got it.  That's unfortunate.  Maybe you should open a new SO question to ask about that.  What is the MIME type that the Google Drive API gives you for those files?  Does it seem to be the correct type for each file extension?  Maybe whichever browser you're using on Linux doesn't know how to deal with these file types directly.  Have you tried opening one of these files with something like LibreOffice?  Maybe they are in fact valid document files, and it's just that the browser can't handle displaying them.  I wouldn't think that would be the case for ".doc" files though.

Comment: ok thanks, I get mime type of docx file as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

Comment: Sounds right, per what I Googled earlier to include that type in my answer.  I'm sorry that I can't be of help with this particular mystery.